# How to add a timer to a dynamic created labels in a winform C#?

Tags: c#, timer, label

I have a small app that creates dynamically a panel that includes a table layout panel where there is a list box and a label. The question is how I'm gonna assign a timer in every label created dynamically and also how I'm gonna start the timer from 00:00? I have tried this code but only adds the timer to the last label in the last panel created:

```
public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
    p = new Panel();
    p.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(360, 500);
    p.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    p.Name = "panel";
    tpanel = new TableLayoutPanel();
    tpanel.Name = "tablepanel";
    ListBox lb = new ListBox();
    tpanel.Controls.Add(lb = new ListBox() {
        Text = "qtylistBox2"
    }, 1, 3);
    Label l6 = new Label();
    tpanel.Controls.Add(l6 = new Label() {
        Text = "0"
    }, 2, 1)
    //here is the timer that i created
    timer1.Interval = 1000;
    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        l6.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("mm\\:ss");
    }
...
}
```

Comment: your timer tick code must be incomplete or different as the I6 you use in the previous method is local.. however, it seems like you need to rethink some of how you would do this.  Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
private Dictionary<Timer, DateTime> Timers = new Dictionary<Timer, DateTime>();

public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  var p = new Panel();
  p.Size = new Size(360, 500);
  p.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
  p.Name = "panel";
  Controls.Add(p);

  var tpanel = new TableLayoutPanel();
  tpanel.Name = "tablepanel";
  tpanel.Controls.Add(new ListBox() { Text = "qtylistBox2" }, 1, 3);
  p.Controls.Add(tpanel);

  Action<string, int, int> createLabel = (text, x, y) =>
  {
    var label = new Label();
    label.Text = text;
    tpanel.Controls.Add(label, x, y);
    var timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = 1000;
    timer.Tick += (sender, e) => 
    {
      label.Text = DateTime.Now.Subtract(Timers[sender as Timer]).ToString("mm\\:ss");
    };
    Timers.Add(timer, DateTime.Now);
  };

  // create one label
  createLabel("0", 2, 1);

  // create other label
  // createLabel("", 0, 0);

  foreach ( var item in Timers )
    item.Key.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: worked perfectly thank you...but one more question how i m gonna start the timer from 00:00? it started from the current datetime