# how to change the backcolor for every dynamically created label after a specific timer? WinForms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I have a tablelayout that includes a label and a timer created dynamically each time. So when the code runs, it creates a tablelayout that has its own specific timer and a label. The question here is how to change the backcolor of each label depending on its own timer created with it. To be more clear, for example I want every 30 seconds to change the color, but the problem that I am facing is that it changes the backcolor of the last created label.
My code :

```
public void Form1_Load()
{
    Label l6 = new Label();
    tpanel0 = new TableLayoutPanel();

    Action<Label> createTimer = l6 =>
    {
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(OnTick);
        var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Tick += (Sender, ee) => { l6.Text =DateTime.Now.Subtract(Timers[Sender as System.Windows.Forms.Timer]).ToString("mm\\:ss"); };
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        Timers.Add(timer, DateTime.Now);
    };
}

private void OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    //I have tried a loop here but only change the color of the last created label

}
```

Comment: An easier solution would be to wrap up the label and timer into a user control. That way, all you have to do is simply set the properties for the user control and add it to the form dynamically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a timer to a dynamic created labels in a winform C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58167811/how-to-add-a-timer-to-a-dynamic-created-labels-in-a-winform-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a Custom User Control and maintaining the connections to one another would be the best way to go.

However, if this is a very simple application and you don't want to do to the hassle of setting all of this up then try this.

At any given **timer tick** find all the **Labels** in your Form and set the Label **BackgroundColor** respectively.

This is a sample Extension method for finding all Controls in your Form that are Labels.

```
public static IEnumerable<System.Windows.Forms.Control> GetAllControlsOfType(this System.Windows.Forms.Control control, Type type)
        {
            var controls = control.Controls.Cast<System.Windows.Forms.Control>();

            return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAllControlsOfType(ctrl, type))
                                      .Concat(controls)
                                      .Where(c => c.GetType() == type);
        }

private void OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    var labels = this.GetAllControlsOfType(typeof(Label));
    foreach(var lb in labels){
    lb.BackgroundColor = //Set the BackgroundColor Property here 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to learn about the reactive UI, which helps you to create forms that change their content dynamically in real-time.
https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI